# What are the similarities and differences between ChatGPT and YouChat?

Tags: comparison, open-ai, chat-bots, chatgpt, youchat

I have recently tried the both, and it looks to me that the both have similar capabilities.

- YouChat says ChatGPT is more advanced.
- YouChat has connection to the Internet, and according to it, constantly self-improves based on user's feedback it determines as positive and negative and in knowledge from the Internet on AI technology. It says it has access to the previous discussions. ChatGPT has no access to the Web and says it has no access to the previous discussions. It seems ChatGPT's jail is more profound.
- Replies by YouChat are generally shorter and have less pre-trained phrasing.
- ChatGPT seems to be more polite and more readily admits mistakes.
- Neither has sense of humor.
- The both know multiple languages, in my impression the both know Russian to the same extent (good).
- Reportedly, YouChat better solves logical questions (like finding the age of the relatives, etc).
- The both have bad arithmetic skills regarding multiplying 4-digit numbers or taking integrals. YouChat cannot understand what is column multiplication, ChatGPT attempts but does it wrong.
- The both can pretend to be an operating system of your choice.
- The both can code and output limited ASCII art.

There are also similar bugs, like truncated output in Russian and some code blocks, which strongly suggest the both systems use the same technology created by the same people, but I could not find anything on this online.

So, what's the relation between the two systems? Are they using the same technology? I would not expect the creators introduced similar bugs into independently created systems. Is there connection between the creators?